# Литература по JavaFX

Tags: java, gui, javafx

Посоветуйте литературу по JavaFX.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

На русском я видел несколько книг по **JavaFX**, и они есть в Интернете. Как справочник на русском часто использую книгу Тимура Машнина "[JavaFX 2.0 Разработка RIA-приложений](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/7968121/?partner=ilja_blog)". В ней есть вся нужная информация относительно компонентов и оформления их с помощью fxcss, работы с анимацией, воспроизведения видео и аудио, и конечно относительно работы с FXML.

Я бы еще обратил внимание на эту книгу на русском по [Java 8](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/30196193/?partner=ilja_blog) от 2015 года, чтобы быть в курсе всех инноваций, который случились с Java за последние несколько лет.

Если с английским не совсем плохо, есть книга от Oracle "[Quick Start Guide to JavaFX](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/24285073/?partner=ilja_blog)" 2013 года, правда на английском, но за-то актуальность ее повыше книги Тимура Машина. Есть и [новое](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/27572803/?partner=ilja_blog) издание этой книги от 2014 года.

Посмотрите [этот](https://www.google.ru/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#q=javafx+books&newwindow=1&tbm=bks) еще список с google books, там есть приличное количество книг, но, правда, на английском. Помимо книг, конечно, используйте официальную Oracle'вскую справку, там иногда все, что нужно, можно найти, или здесь вопрос задать. Так как технология довольно новая и *литература по JavaFX* быстро устаревает, но фундамент практически не меняется, по крайне мере зная его будет проще адаптироваться под новые реалии.

Удачи в учении!

Answer (score 0):

могу скинуть 3 задние по JavaFX (институтские) очень хорошо покрывают основы, интересные и конечный результат тоже) (по англ.,  правда но понятно).

Изучение JavaFX:

http://javafx-guide.blogspot.ie/p/javafx.html

http://code.makery.ch/library/javafx-8-tutorial/ru/