# Создание графического интерфейса без зависимостей

Tags: java, awt, jframe

Как я вижу в Java уже входит `jFrame` и `awt`, которые нужны для создания пользовательских интерфейсов. Передо мной была поставлена задача создать много функциональный интерфейс.

Неужели все программисты Java используют базовые вещи вроде `JFrame` или `awt`?

Возможно ли обойтись без этих зависимостей и создать свой интерфейс с 0 (Знаю что это будет не легко)?

Я ни разу не работал с графическими интерфейсами в Java.

Answer (score 1):

Хороший вопрос!

Для создания пользовательского интерфейса сейчас используется JavaFX. Посмотри в Youtube и в интернете уроки на эту тему

загляни еще на эту страницу - [ссылка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/376383/%D0%9B%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE-javafx/377697#377697). Вдруг поможет.

Comment: На сколько я понял текст вопроса, автор интересуется как создать графический интерфейс пользователя без использования GUI-библиотек, типа AWT, Swing и JavaFX.

Comment: Чем же он хороший? На мой взгляд, он является следствием непонимания базовых принципов платформы, да ещё и плохо сформулирован.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev тогда я тут бессилен